# Android - Communications between a widget and its app

Tags: android, android-widget, communication, android-pendingintent

I have a widget that shows various images with text below, and the same UI set up in the app itself.  I want the widget to not only be able to open the app, but to open the app based on which picture is showing in the widget and then show that same image in the app.  However, I am having a tough time getting this to work.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly have you tried, what didn't work? Also post some relevant source snippets please.

Comment: You can use `Intent`s and `Bundle`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say there are several images in the ui, you can set different Intent for each image, and these intents each will target a different activity.

This post: http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2012/10/communication-between-android-widget.html may give you some hints.

Comment: It's been some time since I worked on this, but I believe what you suggested is what we did.  However, we had to pass a random number to the requestCode parameter of the getActivity().  Otherwise Android was reusing pending intents across remoteViews even though they all had clearly been assigned their own PendingIntent objects.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in **`widget.java`** file to launch your application. instead of `MainActivity.class` you can call any activity

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                    int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.mywidget_provider);
        Intent openApp = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,openApp,0);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnOpenApp,pIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);
}
```