# CyanogenMod and OpenGL ES texture loading

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, cyanogenmod

My friend tested my application on a Motorola Defy (with CyanogenMod v4.x, I don't remember exact version number, and she is not reachable now).

My app uses OpenGL ES (v1.1, and in another activity, v2.0). She reported that during each "new game" start, several textures are missing, so game graphics is partially rendered only. Sometimes all textures are loaded.(Note that we release textures properly. No leak is present.)

We use power-of-two textures. The app works fine on a variety of non-CyanogenMod Android devices (including phones and tablets with Android versions between 2.2 and 4.2). That is, it worked fine on all test devices we've tested it on so far.

OpenGL ES does not return any glError, but I noticed that some texture IDs are negative (they are stored in an `int` in Java, so I thought this is OK). Unlike in case of standard Android devices (where texture IDs are 1,2,3,4,...), this device seems to return totally random-looking texture IDs.

Do I have to worry about this issue? Or is it possible that CyanogenMod is to be blamed, and I won't have issues when selling the app on Google Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motorola Defy has the same hardware -almost- than my Nexus one: low internal memory, old and so on. Official version of Android is 2.3.3 for they.

Yesterday I have installed CyanogenMod. Now  I have Android 4.2.2 on it. I have tested the API  Demos at OS->Sensors->Rotation Vector. That uses OpenGL 1.0 or 1.1 , but not 2.0.

With old Android 2.3.3 it worked and now not => CyanogenMod is to be blamed.  - or just missing the hardware requirements for this functionality.

> I won't have issues when selling the app on Google Play?

Just check any app, which has 500,000 downloads or more! Some people doesn't read app descriptions, just want to tap a button and see an action. If they can't see an action in they point of view aren't they fault, because they taped on other app and that worked and don't care abut your description.

As how they don't care about your app and want action, you should don't care about they and accept they negative reviews. Those ppl are present in SO too: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8176137/529543) nicely asking a user a question and other want to see code, nothing else, just action, they don't care about text ( question).