# How to pass a value from home screen widget to the application?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, widget, android-widget

I am working with an android project for which I want to create a widget. Using this widget I have to control some actions of the control (that is by pressing the stop button from widget the app should stop working of some action). For that I have to pass some value to app from the widget on a button click. So far I am able to do the following:

- open an activity on button click
- open an URL on button click
- make a toast on home screen on button click

Any help is appreciated,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully completed this part of my project.There are two scenarios

1. When we are passing values the app will be launched. That is we are passing the values directly to an activity
2. With out launching the app we can pass the values.Here we are using service

In both situation we can use two method

1. Using `sharedpreferences`
2. Using `Intent(putExtra())`

If you want pass the value directly to an activity(the App will be launched while passing the value) you can use second method above mentioned and call the activity(which activity you wanted to be launched) as follows:

```
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PunchIn, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

this code to launch MainActivity from widget button click. In Inten you can use putExtra() to pass values.better to not use sharedpreference here.

For passing value with out launchingthe app,you can call service from widget button then you can add whatever code you want to add in the `service.class` file. you can call the service as follows:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PunchIn, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

from this service class you can pass values to the application using `SharedPrefernce` or `putExtra()`.

if you want to make a button widget which work same as button click of the app you can use second method. Here you can call a service on on button click as mentioned above, Then write code for the button click in the service class.

i am new to android,i worked with widget in my project for that researched a lot and it took lots of time. so thought about posting this which will help anyone like me. if you found any error/mistake please correct me.happy to correct my mistake. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with this problem because I have not try widget yet.

When button click, send a boardcast message. And your app needs to run a service to receive the message. You can put your values in the message?

Wish this link may give you some ideas:
http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2012/10/communication-between-android-widget.html

There is a similar question:[Android - Communications between a widget and its app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176137/android-communications-between-a-widget-and-its-app)

Good luck!